Playwright attempts installation of fallback packages every time application is run
I am trying to use the Python program boldigger3 which uses Playwright. I am running Linux Mint, which although based on Ubuntu, isn't officially supported by Playwright. This means that I get the message:
BEWARE: your OS is not officially supported by Playwright; installing dependencies for ubuntu24.04-x64 as a fallback.

It then asks for root access and installs the Playwright dependencies. Fine. I run playwright install and it installs the necessary browsers. Fine. But then when I run boldigger3, I get the above message again, and it tries to install the dependencies again – only now all of them "are already the newest version". This happens every time I run boldigger3, which isn't only annoying, but since it asks for my password every time, this complicates making a pipeline with boldigger. It seems to work fine though once it's done with the attempted dependency installations.
I have boldigger3 installed through pip in its own conda environment. Whether I install Playwright through conda or pip into the conda environment doesn't seem to matter. My question is simple: What am I doing wrong? How do I prevent this from happening?
